# What's the damage from calling inherited incorrectly?

Tags: delphi

In searching for a highly intermittent memory corruption in a Delphi XE program, I have found a class constructor which initializes a few fields in the class, and *then* calls inherited.  I believe the initializations were added after the constructor was first written, and accidentally in the wrong place.  I have now corrected it to call inherited first.  The exceptions from the memory corruption almost always occur in a method of this class.

Question: is it possible that this mistake caused an intermittent memory corruption?  In tracing the code, it seems not, but I would really like this fix to be what solves the intermittent issue.  That it does not occur for a while after fixing the problem will not prove that it has gone away.

Some code:

```
Tmyclass = class
  ctype : integer;
  ts : tstringlist;
  th : thandle;
public
  Constructor Create;
  Destructor Destroy; override;
  ...
end;

Constructor Tmyclass.Create;
begin
  ctype := 3;
  doinit;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Show us some code. All sorts of things could be wrong, or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are typical steps of an object creation:

- Memory allocation of the object instance;
- Fill all memory with zero (to initialize all fields, especially string);
- Call all nested constructors, beginning with the latest child, letting `inherited` call every parent - that is why you shall write `inherited` in both constructors and destructors.

So, `inherited` calls the parent method - you can even specify a parent level, or call none if you are sure you can do that (but may break the SOLID principles).

In fact, when a `constructor` is called, there is an hidden parameter added to the method:

> Constructors and destructors use the same calling conventions as other
>   methods, except that an additional Boolean flag parameter is passed to
>   indicate the context of the constructor or destructor call.
>
> A value of False in the flag parameter of a constructor call indicates
>   that the constructor was invoked through an instance object or using
>   the inherited keyword. In this case, the constructor behaves like an
>   ordinary method. A value of True in the flag parameter of a
>   constructor call indicates that the constructor was invoked through a
>   class reference. In this case, the constructor creates an instance of
>   the class given by Self, and returns a reference to the newly created
>   object in EAX.
>
> A value of False in the flag parameter of a destructor call indicates
>   that the destructor was invoked using the inherited keyword. In this
>   case, the destructor behaves like an ordinary method. A value of True
>   in the flag parameter of a destructor call indicates that the
>   destructor was invoked through an instance object. In this case, the
>   destructor deallocates the instance given by Self just before
>   returning.
>
> The flag parameter behaves as if it were declared before all other
>   parameters. Under the register convention, it is passed in the DL
>   register. Under the pascal convention, it is pushed before all other
>   parameters. Under the cdecl, stdcall, and safecall conventions, it is
>   pushed just before the Self parameter.

Source: [official Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control)

So you can be sure that, wherever the `inherited` is called, it will be safely handled. For instance, initialization of fields (reset to 0) will be processed only once, before all constructors are called.

The `TObject.Create` default constructor (the one called in your `inherited` line) is just a `begin end` void block, which does nothing. It is not even necessary/mandatory to call `inherited` here, but it is a good habit, since if you change your object hierarchy, it may be needed afterall.

Only issue may be if some fields are set inside this `inherited` method (`ctype := 2` e.g.), after having been set in the child - but this is not compiler's fault, this is up to user code!

Answer (score 1):

Initializing some fields before calling the inherited constructor is not necessarily a bug. Sometimes the inherited constructor calls some virtual methods which have been overridden by the descendant and these new implementations rely on those fields to be correctly initialized.

(I am not saying that this is good design, but it's not a bug.)

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi you can initialize object fields before calling inherited constructor (it does not worked in Turbo Pascal or 'old' object model, but it is allowed in Delphi 'new' object model).